# Is posting unencrypted passwords to an HTTPS server unsafe?

Tags: php, rest, security, ssl

I have a PHP page on my SSL server which acts as a REST API effectively. What I need to do is take the unencrypted password from a different domain and POST to my page.  After this, the server returns the encrypted data in JSON. I do this with my current website as a POST from the same domain is completely secure but I am not sure about from a different domain? Is there any way a hacker can intercept the POST data before it is encrypted?

Thanks

Kabeer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't comprehend what you're describing in your question,  but as for your title:

> Is posting unencrypted passwords to an HTTPS server unsafe?

No, it is completely safe. Millions of websites do this every day via their login forms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving the POST data via HTTPS, then it is encrypted in transit and not easily intercepted.  It is encrypted using a shared symmetric key between the client and the server, so that only they can decrypt each other's messages.

See [How exactly HTTPS (ssl) works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241991/how-exactly-https-ssl-works)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it is safe, but I would agree that it is fairly common to pass unencrypted user/pass and only depend on TLS/SSL...
TLS/SSL has been compromised a few times over the last couple of years, so depending entirely on it can involve risk.