# How to hide Angular response from API call in the network tab

Tags: angular, api, security, response

Is there any option to hide an Angular response from API call  in the browser network tab like below image data

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide data from network tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54939397/how-to-hide-data-from-network-tab)

Comment: No, there's no way to hide it. If you're trying to keep something secret and safe in a browser, forget it.

Comment: Network response will be shown there. You can configure your server with https so that communication can be secured. And if you have sensitive data, then use encryption/decryption algorithms to protect it. @aruna-wijethunga

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a **web worker**

I believe this is the desired result:

[image]

To achieve this, after making an api call inside a worker, make sure to call `worker.terminate()` which will evict the content from response