How to hide resp JSON data in network tab in order to maintain quiz apps?
When we call an API in react App in network tab the data is fetched and shown in response, but It shows the answers with the fetched data.
How can I hide it? How can the data be hidden to the users? is it possible that we can hide the JSON data fetched from network tab or should we use any other method to write the API?
https://quiz-context-api.vercel.app/

Hi, This may not be possible. Request you may please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54939397/how-to-hide-data-from-network-tab

I tried a few questions in the app, for a outsider all the options would look like the same. Only the person who knows the answer can understand the data shown in the network tab. This is the same as he or she sees it in the Quiz screen.

If the user shouldn’t have this data, why send it to them in the first place?  Only return to the client data that they are permitted to have.

Unfortunately you can't do that. I suggest to rewrite your enpoints for sending data that users have to see on every step only.
For example GET /questions and POST /confirm.
In that case POST /confirm endpoint has to return results for users` answers.
